# optimizing search query with criteria combination

Tags: algorithm, search, grails, if-statement

i have a list of search inputs ( 4 search inputs ) , as criteria i have to do a combination to get a list of books ( by author , by publish date , by name , by number of pages )

this is the code

```
if((author!="") && (date!="")&&(name!="")&&(numPages!="")){

        //query getting the books with th 4 criteria 
        }else{ if((author!="") &&(name!="")&&(numPages!="") ){
                        //query getting the books with th 3 criteria 

}   
 } etc
```

is there a better way to do the combination of those criteria

**EDIT**
this is one of the queries with criteria :

```
def invoiceListbyAll=Invoice.createCriteria().list {
            eq("author", authorObj)
            eq("name", name)
            eq("numPages", numPages)

        }
```

Comment: Would cases be an option here? That said, what about using a loop to loop through all possible unique ID's that correspond to search input labels? Or, could you take the other suggestion and use equals().

Comment: Do NOT use `==` and `!=` to check equality of strings. Use `equals()`. (`==`,`!=` check for identity - which is most often not what you want, while `equals()` checks for equality).

Comment: I don't think you always need to check the value of the variables. its depends on how you do your query

Comment: Please add a snap of how you get the book with some criterias - the answer might heavily depend on it.

Comment: I agree with @amit. Some more complete code and a small data set that we could work with might help immensely.

Comment: Assuming the criteria are `String` type objects,(besides the `.equals` thing to check for empty Strings) you'll have to also watch out for `null` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it as:

```
def invoiceListbyAll=Invoice.createCriteria().list {
    // from your code I assume that all parameter are strings
    if (author) { // groovy empty strings act as boolean false
        eq("author", authorObj)
    }
    if (name) {
        eq("name", name)
    }
    if (numPages) {
        eq("numPages", numPages)
    }

}
```